# Top X by Day, by Person

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've hit a roadblock and can't seem to figure this out. I suspect the answer is staring me in the face, but can't seem to wrap my brain around it and I can't find a solution online.

I'm trying to find the last order completed by each employee for each day in a given range. The problem is the order numbers aren't sequential, so I can't just use a MAX() function to find it. In the end, I don't need anything *except* a list of OrderNums (the last one for each employee each day) because this is going to feed into another query.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT      
    (SELECT USERNAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE TechID = Invoices.TechID1) AS "Tech"
            ,CONVERT(date, OrderDate) AS "OrderDate"
        FROM Invoices
                WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -60, GETDATE())) AND CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
        GROUP BY
            TechID1, OrderDate

        ORDER BY    
            "Tech" DESC, OrderDate DESC
```

This returns one line for each employee each day, which is great, but I can't figure out how to specify the last order number for each day. The best field for this is TimeOut (time the invoice was finished), so I've been trying to add a row in the SELECT clause like

```
(SELECT TOP 1 OrderNum FROM Invoices ii Where ii.TechID1 = Invoices.TechID1 AND ii.OrderDate = Invoices.OrderDate ORDER BY TimeOut DESC)
```

but this isn't consistent *and* it seems like there should be an easier way to do this. It seems like you should be able to just add OrderNum to the SELECT clause but that raises an error (42000 - [SQL Server]Column 'Invoices.OrderNum' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.)

Any advice?

P.S. You guys are awesome. I get *lots* of questions answered by scouring this site. I can't yet reply here because I'm too green, so I'll say thanks now!

**--EDIT--**

*Gordon Linhoff* - Thanks for the suggestion. This is helpful but it's only returning a couple of results per person and we're expecting something closer 40 over the 60 day period. I'll do some digging on this operation because I didn't know it was a thing. I'm still pretty new to SQL.

*McNets* and *ydoow* - I'm not sure what all details you'd like, but hopefully this is helpful:

Invoices Table

- LocationID
- InvoiceNum
- WorkDate
- TimeOut
- TechID1
- (loads of other columns that aren't likely to be helpful here.)

EmployeesTable

- Username
- TechID
- (loads of other columns that aren't likely to be helpful here.)

Also if this helps, the current query looks something like this:

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM Invoices WHERE 
    OrderNum IN (
        SELECT "Last OrderNum" FROM 
        (SELECT 
            (SELECT TOP 1 OrderNum FROM PestPac.dbo.INVOICES WHERE (TechID1 = Employees.TechID OR TechID2 = Employees.TechID)  
                    AND NOT (OrderNum IS NULL)
                    AND NOT (InvoiceType = 'NS') --Not Serviced
                    AND VOID = 0 --Not Voided
                    AND CONVERT(date,WorkDate)= CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()))
                    AND NOT (OrderType = 'NS') ORDER BY WorkDate DESC) AS "Last OrderNum" 
                    FROM Employees
                    WHERE
                        AND Employees.active = 1 
        ) todayMinusSeven)
OR
    OrderNum IN (...) todayMinusSix)
OR
    OrderNum IN (...) todayMinusFive)
OR
    OrderNum IN (...) todayMinusFour)
OR
    OrderNum IN (...) todayMinusThree)
OR
    OrderNum IN (...) todayMinusTwo)
OR
    OrderNum IN (...) todayMinusOne)
```

Essentially, I'm using subqueries against the employees table to get the last order number done by each guy on a given day, then repeating that same query  with just the target day changed. This gives me 7 lists of order numbers that I turn around and use to filter down the Invoice table then get the data I want from there. It's a *very* inelegant weapon for a civilized time. As mentioned above, the goal with this change is to have a single subquery with a *Workdate BETWEEN X and Y* clause.

Comment: Please, add a minimum table schema of employees and invoices.

Comment: Looks like a problem can be solved by common table expression? Would be easier if you can provide sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  I think you can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM (SELECT i.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TechId1, CONVERT(date, OrderDate) ORDER BY OrderDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Invoices i
      WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -60, GETDATE())) AND CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
     ) i
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This selects the entire row.  You can choose the specific columns that you want.